# Customized Twitter Bootstrap 3 Carousel Adds Vertical / Horizontal Scroll Bars

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good morning,

I'm working on a new website that will feature a carousel / information piece that takes up the full 12 columns in width. The div will have an off white background, the carousel will be overlaid for 9 columns and the information about the current slide will be to the right of this for 3 columns.

On larger screens, this is displaying correctly (for the most part, some issues still with the location of the controls), but when this resizes to mobile and some other smaller sizes the browser will add a vertical and sometimes horizontal scroll bar (such as seen in the below image)

A live example can be seen at:

```
http://162.243.29.11/HSCBored/
```

[image: Example of the problem]

The HTML for the carousel is:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9" id="inJumbotronSlider">
                    <div id="mainCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <!--Indicators -->
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#mainCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#mainCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#mainCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ol>

                        <!--Wrapper for slides-->
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <img src="img/slider/img1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="img/slider/img2.jpg" alt="Image 2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="img/slider/img3.jpg" alt="Image 3">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--Controls-->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mainCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mainCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div><!--End Carousel-->
                </div><!--End #inJumbotronSlider-->
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                    <div class="sliderData" id="sliderData1">
                        <h2>LAMBORGHINI CAR SHOW</h2>
                        <p>
                            <strong>DATE:</strong> Thursday, June 27th<br />
                            <strong>LOCATION:</strong> Somewhere, VA<br />
                            <strong>TIME:</strong> 6 &ndash; 11 PM
                        </p>
                        <a href="#" title="Read More About..." class="readMoreButton">
                            READ MORE &raquo;
                        </a>
                    </div><!--End #sliderData1-->
                </div>
            </div><!--End Jumbotron-->
        </div><!--End Row-->
```

The SCSS for the jumbotron is:

```
//
// Jumbotron
// --------------------------------------------------


.jumbotron {
  //padding: $jumbotron-padding;
  margin-bottom: $jumbotron-padding;
  color: $jumbotron-color;
  //background-color: $jumbotron-bg;
  background-color: $warmWhite;
  overflow: auto;

  h1,
  .h1 {
    color: $jumbotron-heading-color;
  }
  p {
    margin-bottom: ($jumbotron-padding / 2);
    //font-size: $jumbotron-font-size;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 2;
    font-weight: 200;
  }

  .container & {
    border-radius: $border-radius-large; // Only round corners at higher resolutions if contained in a container
  }

  .container {
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
    //padding-top:    ($jumbotron-padding * 1.6);
    //padding-bottom: ($jumbotron-padding * 1.6);

    .container & {
      //padding-left:  ($jumbotron-padding * 2);
      padding-right: ($jumbotron-padding * 2);
    }

    h1,
    .h1 {
      font-size: ($font-size-base * 4.5);
    }
    }
    }
```

The SCSS for the carousel is:

```
//
// Carousel
// --------------------------------------------------


// Wrapper for the slide container and indicators
.carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;

  > .item {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    @include transition(.6s ease-in-out left);

    // Account for jankitude on images
    > img,
    > a > img {
      @include img-responsive();
      line-height: 1;
    }
  }

  > .active,
  > .next,
  > .prev { display: block; }

  > .active {
    left: 0;
  }

  > .next,
  > .prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  > .next {
    left: 100%;
  }
  > .prev {
    left: -100%;
  }
  > .next.left,
  > .prev.right {
    left: 0;
  }

  > .active.left {
    left: -100%;
  }
  > .active.right {
    left: 100%;
  }

}

// Left/right controls for nav
// ---------------------------

.carousel-control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: $carousel-control-width;
  @include opacity($carousel-control-opacity);
  font-size: $carousel-control-font-size;
  color: $carousel-control-color;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: $carousel-text-shadow;
  // We can't have this transition here because WebKit cancels the carousel
  // animation if you trip this while in the middle of another animation.

  // Set gradients for backgrounds
  &.left {
    //@include gradient-horizontal($start-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5), $end-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0001));
  }
  &.right {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    //@include gradient-horizontal($start-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0001), $end-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5));
  }

  // Hover/focus state
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
    color: $carousel-control-color;
    text-decoration: none;
    @include opacity(.9);
  }

  // Toggles
  .icon-prev,
  .icon-next,
  .glyphicon-chevron-left,
  .glyphicon-chevron-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 5;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .icon-prev,
  .glyphicon-chevron-left {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .icon-next,
  .glyphicon-chevron-right {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .icon-prev,
  .icon-next {
    width:  20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    font-family: serif;
  }

  .icon-prev {
    &:before {
      content: '\2039';// SINGLE LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+2039)
    }
  }
  .icon-next {
    &:before {
      content: '\203a';// SINGLE RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+203A)
    }
  }
}

// Optional indicator pips
//
// Add an unordered list with the following class and add a list item for each
// slide your carousel holds.

.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 15;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: -30%;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;

  li {
    display: inline-block;
    width:  10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 1px;
    text-indent: -999px;
    border: 1px solid $carousel-indicator-border-color;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;

    // IE8-9 hack for event handling
    //
    // Internet Explorer 8-9 does not support clicks on elements without a set
    // `background-color`. We cannot use `filter` since that's not viewed as a
    // background color by the browser. Thus, a hack is needed.
    //
    // For IE8, we set solid black as it doesn't support `rgba()`. For IE9, we
    // set alpha transparency for the best results possible.
    background-color: #000 \9; // IE8
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); // IE9
  }
  .active {
    margin: 0;
    width:  12px;
    height: 12px;
    background-color: $carousel-indicator-active-bg;
  }
}

// Optional captions
// -----------------------------
// Hidden by default for smaller viewports
.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  right: 15%;
  bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: $carousel-caption-color;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: $carousel-text-shadow;
  & .btn {
    text-shadow: none; // No shadow for button elements in carousel-caption
  }
}


// Scale up controls for tablets and up
@media screen and (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {

  // Scale up the controls a smidge
  .carousel-control {
    .glyphicon-chevron-left,
    .glyphicon-chevron-right,
    .icon-prev,
    .icon-next {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      margin-top: -15px;
      margin-left: -15px;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
  }

  // Show and left align the captions
  .carousel-caption {
    left: 20%;
    right: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }

  // Move up the indicators
  .carousel-indicators {
    bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

The SCSS for the information is:

```
/*
* — Slider —
*/
#inJumbotronSlider {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.readMoreButton {
    background-color: $mediumOrange;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.smallReadMoreButton {
    background-color: $mediumOrange;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the scroll bars you just need to change the jumbotrons overflow property to "visible". When it is set to auto it will clip any content that overflows its parent.

```
.jumbotron{
overflow:visible; //let content overflow
......
```

In terms of the layout here a few changes that will help further:

```
// Reduces size of Header so that it fits in to its parents container
@media (max-width: 980px) { 
.sliderData h1{
font-size: 25px;
margin-top:10px;
}
}

// Change your .sliderData h1 font size at lower widths to your preference
```

I'd advise u to reduce the font-size of the other text elements in the .sliderdata section so that the height of it is closer to that of the jumbotron when it is within these widths.